# How can I format a QR code output?

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using this piece of code to create a QR code (thanks Lodder!!):

```
$data .= $codeContents[0]->Nom;
$data .= $codeContents[0]->Cognoms;
$data .= $codeContents[0]->eCorreu;

$tempDir  = JPATH_SITE . '/images/';   
$fileName = 'qr_'.md5($data).'.png';   
$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = JUri::root() .'images/' . $fileName;

if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
    QRcode::png($data, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
}       
echo '<img src="'.$urlRelativeFilePath.'" />';
```

However, I don't like the output when I read it with the phone, as it looks like

> DaniValverdedani.valverde@gmail.com

How can I format it so it looks like

```
Name: Dani Valverde
e-mail: dani.valverde@gmail.com
```

Thank you so much!

Dani

Comment: Reformat `$data` how you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `$data` should look something like this:

```
$data = 'Name: ' . $codeContents[0]->Nom . ' ' 
    . $codeContents[0]->Cognoms . PHP_EOL 
    . 'email:' . $codeContents[0]->eCorreu;
```

Then call `QRcode::png($data, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);`